# Checking if a character if string is '?

Tags: c++, string, char, escaping, character

Suppose I have a string `"Shalini's dog"` and I want to check if any character of the string is equal to `'`. How do I do this? Because this is not working:

```
if ( s [ i ] == ''' )
```

Comment: Hint: What's the ASCII value of `'`? Also: `'\''`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: Welcome! Take a moment to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Probably, you can escape it `'\''`

Answer (score 3):

Use the escape character literal

```
if ( s [ i ] == '\'' )
```

You could use the string method find like

```
if ( s.find( '\'' ) != std::string::npos )
{
    // do something
}
```

If you are dealing with C-strings then you can write

```
if ( strchr( s, '\'' ) )
{
    // do something
}
```